# Rows version history

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm starting to play around with the smartsheet api.  I've been ask to retrieve the version history of the different rows of a sheet.  I can see that the api return a version number with the row, but I can't find any documentation on how to retrieve all of one particular version of a row.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since individual cells might be edited more or fewer times than another cell in the same row, it's not really feasible to specify a specific revision number. You would need to pull the complete history for each cell, and then do your own filtering logic to match whatever criteria you're looking for.

http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-cell-history

According to the API documentation, there is no filter criteria parameter you can specify, so this logic must be done yourself. For instance, you might filter by the last revision that happened before a certain `modifiedAt` value.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about the cell level.